# How to get the cell values (Sheet1 from Google Form, Sheet2 from Formula) to google doc template

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have 2 sheets. Sheet1 is from Google Form and query them to Sheet2 then make the formula. I would like to get the cell values from them to Google Doc template and send the email.  I can get values from Sheet1 but can't from Sheet2. Please help me solve this problem. Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av0YO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zrs3.png)

```js
function onFormSubmit(e){
  var docs_email = e.values[1];
  var Name = e.values[2];
  var Date1 = e.values[3];
  var Date2 = e.values[4];
  var Money1 = e.values[5];
  var Money2 = e.values[6];

  //Values from Sheet2
  var TotalDate = e.values[7];
  var Money3 = e.values[8];
  var TotalMoney = e.values[9];

  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById('Doc ID')  //Temp document ID
  .makeCopy('Report-'+Name)
  .getId();
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  copyDoc.getBody()
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
  copyBody.replaceText('keyName', Name);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDate1', Date1);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDate2', Date2);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyMoney1', Money1);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyMoney2', Money2);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyTotalDate', TotalDate);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyMoney3', Money3);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyTotalMoney', TotalMoney);
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();

  //convert to pdf
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

  //Send the email
  var subject = "Your Report";
  var body = "Dear " +Name+" \n\n"+"<br> This is your report";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(docs_email, subject, body,{htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In order to retrieve the values from the columns "H" to "J" in "Sheet2", `getValues` is used.
- From your question, I could understand that the columns "H" to "J" have the formula. So I thought that `getLastRow()` might not be able to be directly used. So I thought that it is required to retrieve the 1st empty row at the column "A".

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
var TotalDate = e.values[7];
var Money3 = e.values[8];
var TotalMoney = e.values[9];
```

To:

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();  // This might be not required.
var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2");  // Values are retrieved from the sheet name of "Sheet2".
var row = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
  if (sheet.getRange(i, 1).isBlank()) {
    row = i - 1;
    break;
  }
}
var [TotalDate, Money3, TotalMoney] = sheet.getRange(row, 8, 1, 3).getValues()[0];
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Comment: @Chontisa Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.